# Help me identify module on ceramic substrate

Tags: pcb, identification

I received a couple bonus modules in an ebay purchase and I'm very curious as to what they are.
I have two identical ones, they appear to be 1960s tech.
[image: Top]
[image: Bottom]
[image: Side]

Comment: use the top of the module to sharpen kitchen knives ... works really well

Comment: It seems that ebay are shipping obscure unwanted things to customers so that they have to take responsibility for disposal. Ask ebay whether the thing is Rohs compliant and what precautions you need to take with it. Never look a gift horse in the mouth is an old saying but, in this case, I think you need to.

Comment: It's full of gold. I will probably just recycle it carefully. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't going to destroy something that had real value to someone else for a small amount of gold.

Comment: Find a place that can X-ray it for you.  Many PCB assembly houses have an X-ray machine for inspecting BGAs..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a poor use of resources to try to identify crap that people find. Just toss it so we can spend time on truly needy causes instead.

Comment: No need to be salty, just do it

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, Your chip could be anything.  Development prototypes were often made like this in a lab or, in the case of a module, a workbench. A 1960s era development would be much less refined.  The crimped leads, epoxy potting on the bottom, I'm guessing it was late 1970s to early 1990s tech.

Comment: I figured, but there's always the chance that some grizzled old salt might recognize it.

Comment: This one doesn't.

Comment: The epoxy will probably lose strength when heated to 100C. You can carefully scrape it off and see what is underneath.

Comment: Always a tough decision - explore and discover then through it in the bin, or keep it as a museum piece. There is no wrong answer.